# How to spot errors reported by pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex

When I use pdflatex to compile a tex file into a pdf file, it generates lots of lots of output.

Unlike gcc, which mention again all the errors and warnings at the end, I don't find pdflatex behave the same way. Or do I miss something?

How do you spot errors and warnings reported by pdflatex?

Thanks.

Comment: What say all those lots of warnings? Have you looked into the log file to know what they say?

Comment: I searched in the log file, no "error" is there. There is one "warning" but saying something I guess probably not relevant.

Comment: Are you saying that it generates lots of errors and warnings but that they are not recorded in the log file? By default, compilation will stop on error in any case. Only if you have specified non-stop mode will it try to continue without any interaction from you. (Warnings are different as they are just warnings.)

Comment: @cfr: (1) I didn't set up nonstop mode, unless it is the default, which i don't know how to find out. (2) Lots of terminal outputs already gone out of the scroll-able range, and I don't understand almost all of it, so I don't know if it reports some error. But in the log file, there is no word "error". (3) Is the log file supposed to be the same as the output on the terminal?

Comment: @Tim The log is generally more detailed. If you compile at the command line, non-stop is not default. If you use an editor, it might be. Most terminal emulators allow you to increase the scroll-back. Many allow you to set it to an infinite value. (This is one of the things I require of a terminal emulator.) You can also redirect output to a file if you prefer. How to do this depends on you OS. On Unix-like systems, at least, it depends on you shell.

Comment: You may be also interested in `--file-line-error` option to `pdflatex` to get C type errors.

Comment: @HarishKumar: interesting. what do you mean by C type errors?

Answer (score 1):

The tool [ltx2any](https://github.com/reitzig/ltx2any/wiki) may solve your problem, it creates nice summaries of any errors and warnings for example in pdf or markdown. An example of such a summary:

[image]

(some editors, for example texstudio, can also show you an overview of errors and warnings, but ltx2any has the big advantage that it shows you the full message, not just the first line)